# Access to docker container like an URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb

I have an application developed with PHP, Nginx and dynamodb. I have create a simple docker-compose to work in local.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx_broadway_demo:
    container_name: nginx_broadway_demo
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    links:
      - php_fpm_broadway_demo

  php_fpm_broadway_demo:
    container_name: php_fpm_broadway_demo
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/web

  dynamodb:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    expose:
      - 8000
```

Now I need to add dynamodb URL params to allows PHP to make queries to the database.
So, if I make a ping from PHP docker container like this works fine:

```
ping dynamodb
```

This doesn't work.

```
ping http://dynamodb:8000
```

I need to use http://dynamodb:8000 because AWS needs a URI because I have this error if I use http://dynamodb:8000:

```
Endpoints must be full URIs and include a scheme and host
```

So: how can I call a docker container like an URL?
I have tried with docker-compose parameters like: `depends`, `links`, `network` without success

Comment: `ping http://dynamodb:8000` - this would never work for any scheme or port, because you ping hosts, not ports, and definitely not http.

Comment: ok, so how can I solve the aws problem that needs a full URIs and include a scheme and host? I think it is possible but now I don't ideas on how to do it.

Comment: Your PHP app should be able to talk to Dynamo on `http://dynamodb:8000`. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.Docker.html

Comment: Instead I can't reach dynamodb container and I don't really know why

Comment: I have tried to follow guidelines @Phil without success

Comment: What does your PHP code look like? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62631898/edit) to show how you're trying to connect

Comment: but my doubt is: if I can't ping the container is impossible for my application to works or isn't the same thing?

Comment: Stop worrying about `ping`. If you **must** test `ping`, then the command is `ping dynamodb`. For connecting to dynamo, you use `http://dynamodb:8000`.

Comment: ok, because my problem into my code is that I get this error: AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve: dynamodb
If I try to connect with  `http://dynamodb:8000`
It's very difficult to understand the real problem because the connection to dynamodb it's simple usually.

Comment: Perhaps add a `depends_on` or `links` to your PHP app container so it doesn't start up before dynamo, eg `links: - dynamodb` (just like your NGINX container depends on the PHP container)

Comment: Already tried without success. Same error Domain name not found

Comment: Are you running the PHP code within your `php_fpm_broadway_demo` container? I just tested with a simple app and it works fine for me

Comment: This is my repo: https://github.com/AlessandroMinoccheri/broadway-dynamodb-demo
BRANCH: symfony5 
I am updating and trying many ways... :(

Comment: which and why AWS service need ping? any specific reason? rest of communication between container should work.

Comment: Because I have seen error: Domain not found and I have tried with ping to understand if it can reach the container.

Comment: How you deployed container to aws? if ECS can you show task definition?

Comment: I don't have to deploy the application, I need to work in locally at the moment.

Comment: can we move this to a chat? I might have some ideas for you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the chat, the error come when dependency installed on the host and use inside the container as [composer work base on the underlying platform](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

So we investigate that the issue come due to above reason. installing `dependency` inside the container fix the issue.

```
docker exec -it php bash -c "cd web; composer install"
```